# Rust threading async closure

Tags: multithreading, github, rust

I'm still new with asynchronous/threading in general. I want to spin up a small HTTP server in the background and also listen to the response. So far, this is what I come up with:

```
spinner_newline("Opening your browser...".to_owned());

let x = open::that(build_github_oauth_url());

match x {
    Ok(_) => {
        // This should be a new thread
        setup_oauth_callback_server(|code| {
            spinner_newline("Getting your GitHub information...".to_owned());
            process_signup_github(code).await; // This should be an async calll
        });
    }
    Err(e) => {
        return Err(anyhow!("Failed to open browser: {e}"));
    }
}
/*
try_join!(x, async {
    setup_oauth_callback_server(&|code| {
        spinner_newline("Getting your GitHub information...".to_owned());
        process_signup_github(code)
    })
});
*/
```

That code doesn't compile. I want to execute the process_signup_github when I get the code from the closure. Any pointers? I'm using tokio.

This is the server setup, a slight modification from the Rust cookbook:

```
fn setup_oauth_callback_server(closure: &impl Fn(String)) {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8808").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        handle_connection(stream, closure);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream, closure: impl Fn(String)) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
    let request_line = &buf_reader.lines().next().unwrap().unwrap();

    debug!("Request: {:#?}", request_line);

    let code_regex = Regex::new(r"code=([^&]*)").unwrap();

    let (status_line, filename) = match code_regex.captures(&request_line) {
        Some(group) => {
            let code = group.get(1).unwrap().as_str();
            debug!("Code: {:#?}", code);
            spinner_newline("Authorization complete...".to_owned());
            closure(code.to_owned());
            ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "./src/account/hello.html")
        }
        None => {
            debug!("Code not found.");
            ("HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND", "./src/account/404.html")
        }
    };

    let contents = fs::read_to_string(filename).unwrap();
    let length = contents.len();
    let response = format!("{status_line}\r\nContent-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n{contents}");
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: If this is a modification of the Rust Book example, i assume you don't have a async runtime like Tokio? in that case, running any async function will be impossible. Rust doesn't come with a default async runtime. howevery running it in a thread should be possible.

Comment: Please include the compiler error.

Comment: I do have tokio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a [channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/channels.html) for solving this problem. It's more straightforward for me. So, here's what [the code](https://github.com/smbpndk/smbpndk-cli/blob/598f808ca9cc8341ed9c2bc078e2be2bf9818827/src/account/signup/process.rs#L95-L176) looks like:

```
pub async fn signup_with_github() -> Result<CommandResult> {
    // Spin up a simple localhost server to listen for the GitHub OAuth callback
    // setup_oauth_callback_server();
    // Open the GitHub OAuth URL in the user's browser
    spinner_newline("Getting your GitHub information...".to_owned());

    let rx = match open::that(build_github_oauth_url()) {
        Ok(_) => {
            let (tx, rx): (Sender<String>, Receiver<String>) = mpsc::channel();
            debug!(
                "Setting up OAuth callback server... (tx: {:#?}, rx: {:#?})",
                &tx, &rx
            );
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                setup_oauth_callback_server(tx);
            });
            rx
        }
        Err(_) => {
            let error = anyhow!("Failed to open a browser.");
            return Err(error);
        }
    };

    debug!("Waiting for code from channel...");

    match rx.recv() {
        Ok(code) => {
            debug!("Got code from channel: {:#?}", &code);
            process_signup_github(code).await
        }
        Err(e) => {
            let error = anyhow!("Failed to get code from channel: {e}");
            return Err(error);
        }
    }
}

fn setup_oauth_callback_server(tx: Sender<String>) {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8808").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        handle_connection(stream, tx.clone());
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream, tx: Sender<String>) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
    let request_line = &buf_reader.lines().next().unwrap().unwrap();

    debug!("Request: {:#?}", request_line);

    let code_regex = Regex::new(r"code=([^&]*)").unwrap();

    let (status_line, filename) = match code_regex.captures(&request_line) {
        Some(group) => {
            let code = group.get(1).unwrap().as_str();
            debug!("Code: {:#?}", code);
            debug!("Sending code to channel...");
            debug!("Channel: {:#?}", &tx);
            match tx.send(code.to_string()) {
                Ok(_) => {
                    debug!("Code sent to channel.");
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    debug!("Failed to send code to channel: {e}", e);
                }
            }
            ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "./src/account/hello.html")
        }
        None => {
            debug!("Code not found.");
            ("HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND", "./src/account/404.html")
        }
    };

    let contents = fs::read_to_string(filename).unwrap();
    let length = contents.len();
    let response = format!("{status_line}\r\nContent-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n{contents}");
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
```